# How to Make Androidx.CardView Work for API 28 and Above?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-xml, androidx

I have been using Androidx.CardView in various XML layout files in my Android app, and it has been working well for most Android versions. However, I recently noticed that it's not functioning correctly on Android API 28 (version 9). I want to ensure that my app remains compatible with API 28 and above.

Here's a sample of the XML layout code I've been using:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="250dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/google_sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_google" />
 </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working correctly"? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Card itself is not rendering as expected. But if i remove app:cardCornerRadius card is rendering but without applying radius to it. This problem is only for Android Api 28 and below